# Laravel updateExistingPivot with multiple primary keys

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, insert-update

**Problem**

I want to update a row in a pivot table that have 2 primary keys. But updateExistingPivot want only a single primary key.

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);
```

**My DB-tables**

- Campaign
- User
- Campaign_user (primary keys are user_id and campaign_id)

**My Question**

Should I change my pivot table so it only have 1 primary key called id. Or can I keep it with 2 primary keys, and still update it, with Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

I think for best practice you should add a key id in your Campaign_user table, structure should:

```
Campaign_user
 id|user_id|campaign_id
```

In User Model

```
public function campaign()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Campaign', 'Campaign_user','user_id','campaign_id')->withPivot('extra attribute if any');
}
```

In Campaign Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'Campaign_user','campaign_id','user_id')->withPivot('extra attribute if any');
}
```

Now your code is:

```
$user = App\User::find($userId);
$user->campaign()->updateExistingPivot($campaignId, array('any attribute'=>$value));
```