# updateExistingPivot using the primary key instead of the foreign key

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, laravel-6

I think this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800092/laravel-updateexistingpivot-with-multiple-primary-keys), however I also think my use case is slightly different.

I am successfully able to update a pivot table using [updateExistingPivot](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) when a single user exists; however instead of referencing the FK on the pivot table, I need to reference the `id`.

I have three tables: `users`, `roles` and `role_user`.

```
users
    id|name|email

roles
    id|title

role_user
    id|active|user_id|role_id
```

For example, if I have two users in my application, the `users` table would look like:

```
id: 1|name: foo|email: fooexample@email.com
id: 2|name: bar|email: barexample@email.com
```

My `roles` table looks like this:

```
id: 1|title: fizz
id: 2|title: buzz
id: 3|title: bang
```

Each user is given 3 roles by default. So my `role_user` table looks like this:

```
id: 1|active: true|user_id: 1|role_id: 1
id: 2|active: true|user_id: 1|role_id: 2
id: 3|active: true|user_id: 1|role_id: 3
id: 4|active: true|user_id: 2|role_id: 1
id: 5|active: true|user_id: 2|role_id: 2
id: 6|active: true|user_id: 2|role_id: 3
```

Because `updateExistingPivot` looks at the FK to decide what to update, everything works great with a single user. However, when I have duplicate `user_id` and/or `role_id` FK's things start to fall apart. Instead of looking at the FK, I need to be able to look at the `id` in my pivot table.

I am passing my roles to a vue component from my controller like this:

```
// Get the roles(s) that belong to the user.
$roles = $user->roles
    ->sortByDesc('title')
    ->toJson();
```

I am rendering the list on screen, and when a user clicks a role, they can update it's status:

```
...

async handleRoleClick(event, role) {
    console.log('updating role: ', role);
    try {
        let response = await axios.patch(`/my-path`, {
            active: !this.active,
            id: role.pivot.id,
        });

        // data getting passed is correct.
        // active: false
        // id: 5 <-- the id of the pivot table, not a FK value

        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('response.data', response.data);
            this.active = response.data.role.pivot.active;
            console.log('active: ', this.active);
        } else {
            console.error('Error: could not update role. ', response);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error: sending patch request. ', error);
    }
},
...
```

My update method in my controller looks like this:

```
$attributes = request()->validate([
    'active' => 'required',
    'id' => 'required',
]);

// Get the authenticated user.
$user = auth()->user();

// Update the roles' status in the pivot table.
$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($attributes['id'], $attributes);

// Get the role that was just updated via the relationship.
$role_with_pivot = $user->roles()->where('role_user.id', $attributes['id'])->first();

return response()->json(['role' => $role_with_pivot], 200);
```

The data I am sending in my request headers is correct. I am not getting any errors, however my pivot table is not getting the values I am passing to it. I assume it's because I am not correctly sending the id. In my example above it would be `id: 5`. Because there isn't a `user_id` of `5` or `role_id` of `5`, Laravel isn't sure what to do.

How can I tell Laravel to look at the `id` of the pivot table, and not a foreign key?

Comment: Why don't you just send the role id, instead of primary key of pivot table? And use role id in your vue request and response? A user will have unique role row in pivot table.

Comment: If you know the primary key of the row in the pivot table? Why don't you just query the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing it though *seems* kind of sketchy. I'd be really interested to see if there is a more "Laravel way" of doing this. Everything else is above is the same, here is what my `update` method on my controller looks like.

**controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
{
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'active' => 'required',
        'id' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Get the authenticated user.
    $user = auth()->user();

    // Get the requested role (row) from the pivot table.
    $role = $user->roles()->where('role_user.id', $attributes['id'])->first();

    // Update the requested role.
    $role->pivot->active = $attributes['active'];

    // Save the requested role.
    $role->pivot->save();

    // Get the role that was just updated via it's relationship.
    $role_with_pivot = $user->roles()->where('role_user.id', $attributes['id'])->first();

    return response()->json(['role' => $role_with_pivot], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve role id in you View instead of pivot primary key, and use role_id to update pivot table.

As stated your user has multiple roles, but only one combination of role and user id.

```
async handleRoleClick(event, role) {
    console.log('updating role: ', role);
    try {
        let response = await axios.patch(`/my-path`, {
            active: !this.active,
            id: role.id, //change this
        });

        // data getting passed is correct.
        // active: false
        // id: 5 <-- the id of the pivot table, not a FK value

        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('response.data', response.data);
            this.active = response.data.role.pivot.active;
            console.log('active: ', this.active);
        } else {
            console.error('Error: could not update role. ', response);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error: sending patch request. ', error);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

it's late, but might help some artisans in the future.

You may use DB method directly or create a dedicated model/entity for that table.

e.g

```
DB::table('role_user')->where('id', $id);
```

or

```
RoleUser::find($id);
```